# polynomial regression for payroll examination

Tags: machine-learning, regression, polynomials

I serve as internal auditor in few clients ,one of my client has thousands of employees in different location, most of them in the head office, the client looks for corporate control for the salary monitoring

is it make sense to use the regression method in order to find outliers,
potential parameter can be -years of experience, gender, level/rank etc
I planned to go over all the monthly payroll and look for significant outliers ,because of the differences between the global location, it might be a good idea to focus only in the head office
the idea is to train the model for previous months average and test it for the current month
what do you think is too much effort or theoretical ? or can have a good chance to bring value ?
thank you

Comment: I feel your question would be better suited for [Data Science community](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/104348/outlier-detection-using-regression) answers your question regarding the regression method to use. It makes sense to only use data from the head office, as adding data from different geographies will require you to add more data around general demographics, which you can avoid for a proof of concept.

Coming to the problem itself, you'll need to provide a better explanation of how you're defining outliers. Are you looking for mistakes in payroll? Or are you looking for people who make significantly more/less than their peers? You'll only be able to decide on a modelling framework once you get clarity the basic definitions.

Also, you might want to consider statistical significance tests like Grubbs test (more information on tests [here](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda35h.htm)) first, before moving to machine learning approaches. They're easier to set up and explain to non-practitioners.